# Windows VERSIONINFO information special chars

Tags: c++, windows, string, versioninfo, fileversioninfo

I wonder if there are characters that I should **NOT** use in the VERSIONINFO. Such that potentially will cause problems down the road.

```
    VALUE "CompanyName", "Company Name"
    VALUE "FileDescription", "File Description"
    VALUE "FileVersion", "2.0.0.5"
    VALUE "InternalName", "name.exe"
    VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Legal Copyright"
    VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Original File name"
    VALUE "ProductName", "Product Name"
    VALUE "ProductVersion", "2.0.0.5"
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx

I assume that it is the 'other' app responsibility to consume the strings correctly. I am asking to be on the safe side as this change will affect **many** files.

Need additional information? Just let me know

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know of any limit. As documentation shows a lot of language settings and charsets are possible, so what problems do you expect? Go ahead, change it (and test it)!

Comment: Dev & test is a given. As mentioned above, I do not expect issues. I am asking to be on the safe side as this change will affect many files. I want to make sure I did not overlooked something.